# Out of question body area bound MathJax-ed matrices

Tags: bug, design, mathjax

In this [question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/10998/derivative-of-a-jacobian-matrix) there are wide MathJax formatted matrices, which overlap with the "Hot Network Questions"

[image]

I am using Mozilla Firefox 49.0.2, and I do not know if this occurs with other browsers.

Comment: Possibly related http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/24924/9281 & http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/25180/9281

Comment: Also possibly related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21740/9281

Comment: The issue is the same as the first on listed by Mark Booth.  MathJax does not break wide tables, so they with overflow into the side bar.  You either have to break the entries yourself (using internal `\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}` or nested `\begin{array}...\end{array}` environments), or use a sizing command (like `\small`) to reduce the size of the array, or a combination of the two.  The other two links are to different issues.